# Como saber si un pdf esta protegido con contraseña?

Tags: linux, pdf

Necesito saber, si hay algún comando en linux, que me diga si un archivo pdf esta protegido con contraseña.

Saludos.

Comment: No hay ninguno.

Answer (score 2):

Después de googlear un rato, encontré la solución es comando es `pdfinfo`, que da la siguiente información.

[image: Salida del comando pdfinfo]